# GIT checkin issue while running parallel builds on Travis CI

Tags: git, github, travis-ci, devops

Using travis I am running unit tests using multiple builds as travis has a 120 minute limitation for a build. Each build generates a report and a shell command exports the report to GIT at the end of every build. however there is a GIT check-in conflict when other builds try to check-in the report as master has been updated with a report on GIT. (all report names are different)

Is there a solution for this issue? I want all builds to run parallel, is there a way to force check- in.

Travis.yml:

```
env:

 - TEST_SUITE=GarageTest
- TEST_SUITE=GarageTest2
- TEST_SUITE=Price_Validation
- TEST_SUITE=Price_Validation2
- TEST_SUITE=Geo
- TEST_SUITE=Geo2
#- TEST_SUITE=E2E_Scripts




global:
  - LANG=en_US.UTF-8
language: java
jdk:
- oraclejdk8
script:
- mvn clean
- mvn -Dtest=$TEST_SUITE test

#- mvn test
- cd ../
- ./report_push.sh

before_install:
 - chmod +x report_push.sh
 - cd GaiaAutomationOutPut
 #- chmod 777 target/test-classes/GaiaAutoMation/GaiaAutomationOutPut/AppTest.class

on:
repo: GaiaAutomation/GaiaAutomationOutPut
branches:
only:
- master
```

---

report_push.sh

```
git config user.name "test"
git config user.email "test@in.ibm.com"
git config --global push.default simple
#git checkout reportBranch
#git pull
#git add .
git add *.html
git commit -m "documentation update"
git push -u origin HEAD:master
```

---

Comment: There is forced check-in in git, it's called "forced push": `git push --force`. But it will not help you because every forced push will remove already pushed reports. I think git is unsuitable for such massive parallel pushing. My recommendation is to send files somewhere and there push reports one by one in a queue.

Comment: Or push to different branches and merge/rebase all temporary branches after the run.

Comment: the report file names are different, would force push delete those files as well ?

Comment: `git` doesn't push files, it pushes commits (and files are attached to commits, so to say). Forced push overwrites commits thus removing attached files.

Comment: Thank you, Is there is an alternative for this , I would like to keep all my files. Would git Pull command work before the pus during build.

Comment: Sooner or later there will be 2 parallel pushes and one will be rejected. There is no simple solution. Complex solutions are: a database, a message queue or a job queue.